# Making an action when list reaches a certain amount

Tags: java, list, design-patterns

I have a thread that adds connections to a list. My application needs to do pick 2 random elements when the list gets bigger then two elements.

After that the program does some actions on the connections and then removes the two connections out of the list.

I already tried to make a separate thread run and check if the list is bigger then 2 elements.

When its bigger it picks 2 random elements out of the list and does the action with them, and then removes them from the list.

Is there a better way to do this in a design pattern way? I don't think that running another thread that keeps checking if list is bigger then 2 is a good solution.

Comment: if you want to use multiple threads then you also need to used thread safe collection. Instead of using separate thread for just check list size you can implement something like wrapper over collection and tune operation that add elements into wrapped with check of collection size and trigger some actions based on collection size

Comment: It seems overkill. Threads have a specific requirement : performing these things in parallel. Is is the requirement ? If no, why not simply add elements in the list via a method that after that checks its size and "make" the action which  you refer. You should probably post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your solution with producer consumer problem where one thread is checking the size of List and when the size reaches 2 then other threads starts consuming(removing) from the list. Both addition and removal to the thread should be performed through the synchronized blocks so that no discrepancy happens.

You can try below approach for your problem.

`

```
import java.util.LinkedList; 

public class Threadexample 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException { 
        // Object of a class that has both produce() 
        // and consume() methods 
        final PC pc = new PC();
    // Create producer thread 
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    { 
        @Override
        public void run() 
        { 
            try
            { 
                pc.produce(); 
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 

    // Create consumer thread 
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    { 
        @Override
        public void run() 
        { 
            try
            { 
                pc.consume(); 
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 

    // Start both threads 
    t1.start(); 
    t2.start(); 

    // t1 finishes before t2 
    t1.join(); 
    t2.join(); 
} 

// This class has a list, producer (adds items to list 
// and consumer (removes items). 
public static class PC 
{ 
    // Create a list shared by producer and consumer 
    // Size of list is 2. 
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(); 
    int capacity = 2; 

    // Function called by producer thread 
    public void produce() throws InterruptedException 
    { 
        int value = 0; 
        while (true) 
        { 
            synchronized (this) 
            { 
                // producer thread waits while list 
                // is full 
                while (list.size()==capacity) 
                    wait(); 

                System.out.println("Producer produced-"
                                            + value); 

                // to insert the jobs in the list 
                list.add(value++); 

                // notifies the consumer thread that 
                // now it can start consuming 
                notify(); 

                // makes the working of program easier 
                // to understand 
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    // Function called by consumer thread 
    public void consume() throws InterruptedException 
    { 
        while (true) 
        { 
            synchronized (this) 
            { 
                // consumer thread waits while list 
                // is empty 
                while (list.size()==0) 
                    wait(); 

                //to retrive the ifrst job in the list 
                int val = list.removeFirst(); 

                System.out.println("Consumer consumed-"
                                                + val); 

                // Wake up producer thread 
                notify(); 

                // and sleep 
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

} 
`

have a look here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-solution-using-threads-java/